# Scala Option map to another Option

Tags: scala, scala-option

Is there a way to avoid having to wrap a potentially null result inside another option when mapping from an option.

```
option.flatMap(arg => Option(arg.somePotentiallyNullValue))
```

Eg something like

```
option.optionMap(arg => arg.somePotentiallyNullValue )
```

I just have a lot of Java code in our codebase that means forever wrapping the results of maps in further Option calls.

Comment: The Maybe (Option) monad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about implicit conversion from nullable type to `Option`? Declare this somewhere in scope:

```
implicit def toOption[T](x: T) : Option[T] = Option(x)
```

Later the compiler will figure it out:

```
option.flatMap(_.somePotentiallyNullValue)
```

Since `flatMap` expects `Option[T]` as a result value, compiler uses `toOption` implicit conversion like this:

```
option.flatMap(arg => toOption(arg.somePotentiallyNullValue))
```

Answer (score 1):

The factory method for `Option` will turn a `null` into a `None`:

```
scala> val os1: Option[String] = Option(null)
os1: Option[String] = None
```

**Addendum**

I may have misunderstood your question...

If you restrict its scope judiciously, you can use an implicit conversion:

```
scala> implicit def nullable2Option[T >: Null](t: T): Option[T] = if (t == null) None else Some(t)
warning: there were 1 feature warnings; re-run with -feature for details
nullable2Option: [T >: Null](t: T)Option[T]

scala> val os2: Option[String] = "foo"
os2: Option[String] = Some(foo)

scala> val nullS: String = null
nullS: String = null

scala> val os3: Option[String] = nullS
os3: Option[String] = None
```

This will work any time there's available type information for the compiler to use to drive the attempt to bridge a value of a nullable type to an `Option`. E.g., when calling a method (where the types are always explicit).

Answer (score 1):

In order to make things easier you could introduce a new type:

```
implicit class CheckedOption[T](val option:Option[T])

object CheckedOption {
  @inline implicit def toOption[T](checkedOption:CheckedOption[T]):Option[T] =
    checkedOption.option.flatMap(Option.apply)
}
```

Then in your code, where you use the option instance you do something like this:

```
def use(o:CheckedOption[String]) = {
  o map { value =>
    value + "-Some"
  } getOrElse "None"
}

val option1:Option[String] = Some(null)
val option2:Option[String] = Some("foo")

use(option1) //> res0: String = None
use(option2) //> res1: String = foo-Some
```