# Concise way of mapping null result of Option

Tags: scala

Say I have some class `B` and some class `A` that I do not control:

```
class B
class A { def getB: B = ... }
```

Sometimes the result of `getB` is a valid `B`, and sometimes it is `null`.  I have an optional `A` that I want to get an optional `B` out of.  This is the "simplest" way I could figure out how to do it:

```
val a: Option[A] = ...
val b: Option[B] = a flatMap {x => Option(x.getB)}
```

I wanted to get rid of the named `x`, so I tried this, which isn't simpler:

```
val b: Option[B] = a map {_.getB} flatMap Option.apply
```

I tried composing `_.getB` with `Option`, and the only other thing I got to work was less simple:

```
val b: Option[B] = a flatMap {((x: A) => x.getB) andThen Option.apply _}
```

What is a simpler way?  This seems like it would be a common enough problem that there is an elegant solution.  What I would *really* like to have is something close to this, which is obviously not possible:

```
val b: Option[B] = a flatMap {Option(_.getB)}
```

Comment: "I wanted to get rid of the named x" Why do you want to get rid of it? It seems like the best option here. [Here is why you can't use `_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545168/scala-unexpectedly-not-being-able-to-ascertain-type-for-expanded-function)

Comment: If your concern is dealing with potential `null`s that should be `Option`s in a verbose way, over and over, consider wrapping `A` so that you can treat the problem at the source (by wrapping everything in `Option.apply`).

Comment: @evan058 I can live with `x`, it just feels like boilerplate.  Thanks for the link; I was aware of the reason that particular syntax didn't work, I have just found as I've been learning Scala that it seems to be full of pleasant surprises, so I thought there might be one here as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala Option map to another Option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14921591/scala-option-map-to-another-option)

Comment: @zhelezoglo Did you just seriously delete your answer and downvote my question because somebody downvoted you?  Your answer taught me something, and I did not downvote it, even if it wasn't my accepted answer.

Comment: @Nate I never thought you downvoted my answer. But I think your question is misleading. You first said, you were looking for a way to get rid of _named x_, and posted a couple of ways you tried which were even longer then the original try. Then, 3 hours ago, you said, that _named x_ didn't matter in fact, and all you cared was avoiding boilerplate. But this question is a duplicate then.

Comment: @zhelezoglo You have misread what I wrote.  I never said that named `x` didn't matter.  If named `x` didn't matter, I wouldn't have asked the question.  I said I could live with it even though I didn't like it.  I accepted my fate, that there wasn't an even shorter way.  I asked exactly the question I wanted to ask.

Comment: @Nate Could be. But it doesn't matter, since the question you asked was a duplicate. (I just wanted to explain what first made me think that it was not.) Checkout the answer to what you wanted to ask from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14921591/scala-option-map-to-another-option It's without x, and without boilerplate.

Comment: @zheleoglo I didn't say the questions didn't have overlap.  Their question was not "what [I] wanted to ask".  As I said, I asked what I wanted to ask.  To be clear, I'm not annoyed because you proposed a duplicate - just because you deleted your answer, which I thought was insightful.  If you undelete your answer, I'll even upvote it.

Comment: @Nate To be clear, I'm sure it is a duplicate. But if you insist on that it's not(maybe I'm missing something), I will un-downvote it. This has nothing to do with my answer, you don't need to upvote it if you don't like it. – SO says, you have to edit your question first to let me re-vote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way to make it more concise in-line, but you could use the "enrich my library" pattern to add your own functionality to `A`, such as a method called `safeGetB` that does what you want:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class B
class A {
  def getB: B = null
}

implicit class RichA(a: A) {
  def safeGetB: Option[B] = Option(a.getB)
}

Some(new A()).flatMap(_.safeGetB)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class B
defined class A
defined class RichA
res0: Option[B] = None
```

Comment: Aw, don't offer any hope. Just say there isn't a way that is more concise.

Comment: Great!  A new dark corner of Scala for me to explore. ;^)